# PostgreSql Group By and aggreate function error

Tags: postgresql

My problem is, when I run the following query in MySQL, it looks like this

Query;

```
SELECT
CONCAT(b.tarih, '#', CONCAT(b.enlem, ',', b.boylam), '#', b.aldigi_yol) AS IlkMesaiEnlemBoylamImei,
CONCAT(tson.max_tarih, '#', CONCAT(tson.max_enlem, ',', tson.max_boylam), '#', tson.max_aldigi_yol) AS SonMesaiEnlemBoylamImei,
Max(CAST(b.hiz  AS UNSIGNED)) As EnYuksekHiz,
TIME_FORMAT(Sec_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, (b.tarih), (tson.max_tarih))), '%H:%i') AS DurmaSuresi
FROM
(Select id as max_id, tarih as max_tarih, enlem as max_enlem, boylam as max_boylam, aldigi_yol as max_aldigi_yol from _213gl2015016424 where id in(
SELECT MAX(id)

FROM _213gl2015016424 where (tarih between DATE('2016-11-30 05:45:00') AND Date('2017-01-13 14:19:06')) AND CAST(hiz  AS UNSIGNED) > 0
GROUP BY DATE(tarih))
) tson
LEFT JOIN _213gl2015016424 a ON a.id = tson.max_id
LEFT JOIN _213gl2015016424 b ON DATE(b.tarih) = DATE(a.tarih)
WHERE b.tarih is not null And (b.tarih between DATE('2016-11-30 05:45:00') AND Date('2017-01-13 14:19:06')) AND b.hiz > 0
GROUP BY tson.max_tarih
```

Output is order by date; 
[Result query](https://i.hizliresim.com/rOb2RV.png)

When I try to run a query in PostgreSQL, I get group by mistake.

Query;

```
SELECT
    CONCAT(b.tarih, '#', CONCAT(b.enlem, ',', b.boylam), '#', b.toplamyol) AS IlkMesaiEnlemBoylamImei,
   CONCAT(tson.max_tarih, '#', CONCAT(tson.max_enlem, ',', tson.max_boylam), '#', tson.max_toplamyol) AS SonMesaiEnlemBoylamImei,
   Max(CAST(b.hiz  AS OID)) As EnYuksekHiz,
   to_char(to_timestamp((extract(epoch from (tson.max_tarih)) - extract(epoch from (b.tarih)))) - interval '2 hour','HH24:MI') AS DurmaSuresi
   FROM
   (Select id as max_id, tarih as max_tarih, enlem as max_enlem, boylam as max_boylam, toplamyol as max_toplamyol from _213GL2016008691 where id in(
       SELECT MAX(id)
        FROM _213GL2016008691 where (tarih between DATE('2018-02-01 03:31:54') AND DATE('2018-03-01 03:31:54')) AND CAST(hiz  AS OID) > 0
        GROUP BY DATE(tarih))
        ) tson
    LEFT JOIN _213GL2016008691 a ON a.id = tson.max_id
    LEFT JOIN _213GL2016008691 b ON DATE(b.tarih) = DATE(a.tarih)
    WHERE b.tarih is not null And (b.tarih between DATE('2018-02-12 03:31:54') AND DATE('2018-02-13 03:31:54')) AND b.hiz > 0
    GROUP BY tson.max_tarih
```

Group by error is : To use the aggregate function, you must add the column "b.tarih" to the GROUP BY list.
When I add it I get the same error for another column.I'm waiting for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a feature of MySQL that is not standard SQL and you can also deactivate.
You are grouping by tson.max_tarih in your query. That means that for all rows that share the same value in that field, you will get only one row as a result of that group.

If you have several different values in the rest of the fields (enlem, boylam, etc...) which one are you trying to get in as the result of the query? That's the question that PostgreSQL is asking you.

MySQL is just returning any value for those fields among the rows in the group. PostgreSQL requires you to actually specify it.

Two typical solutions would be grouping by the rest of the fields (b.tarih, b.enlem) or specifying the value those fields to something like MAX(b.tarih), etc.